# How to prove $\lim_\limits{n\to\infty}\int_2^3(\ln x)^n dx =\infty$ without evaluating integral explicitly

Tags: real-analysis, limits

This problem is from introduction to analysis by Athur Mattuck.

Comment: Please use the body of your Question to present a problem in reasonably self-contained fashion.  Citing the source of an exercise is helpful, but it is not clear what the exercise really involves, from the brief title mention.  What sorts of approaches have you considered "without evaluating integral explicitly"?  E.g. if I were to relate this one to another (easy) integral, but evaluate *that* one explicitly, would it meet your requirement?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Note that $e\in [2,3]$ and on the interval $[a,b]=[\frac{e+3}{2},3]$ we have $\ln x\ge q:=\ln \frac{e+3}{2}>1$. As additionally $\ln x>0$ for $2\le x<3$, we find 
$$\int_2^3(\ln x)^n\,\mathrm dx>\int_a^b q^n\,\mathrm dx=(b-a)q^n\to \infty. $$

Comment: Thanks.By the way,I am new here,so where I can practice typing formula correctly